# JPAQuery/QueryDSL Fetch all entities that have a specific item in list (@OneToMany)?

Tags: jpa, querydsl

In resume, I have this:

```
Purchase {
  @OneToMany
  Set<Item> items;
}
```

```
Item {
  Long id;
}
```

How can I get a list of **Purchase** that have a specific **Item** in the list?

This is what I tried to do (probably not the correct way):

```
QPurchase purchase ...
JPAQuery query ...

query.from(purchase).where(
  purchase.items.any().id.eq(xxx)
);
```

But I always get a **SQLException** `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.`

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
QPurchase purchase ...
QItem item ...
JPAQuery query ...

query.from(purchase).
  .join(purchase.item, item)
  .where( item.id.eq(xxx) );
```